# How can I fix line breaks output by script(1) utility?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, sftp, newline

I have the following lftp script to copy files from a remote to local:

```
env TERM=dumb script -a $LOGSTDOUT -c "$(cat <<- EOF
    lftp $PROTOCOL://$URL -u ${USER},${PASS} << EOFF
    set dns:fatal-timeout never
    set sftp:auto-confirm yes
    set mirror:use-pget-n 50
    set mirror:parallel-transfer-count 2
    set mirror:parallel-directories yes
    set mirror:include-regex $REGEX
    set log:enabled/xfer yes
    set log:file/xfer $LOG
    set xfer:use-temp-file yes
    set xfer:temp-file-name *.lftp
    mirror -c -v --loop --Remove-source-dirs "$REMOTEDIR" "$LOCALDIR"
    quit
    EOFF
EOF
)"
```

I am capturing terminal output with the [script(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) utility. The `env TERM=dumb` is just a random piece of code I found to disable ANSI escape codes.

My problem is that the line breaks of the output log file get quiet mangled. It seems to be using CR and LF. I discovered more information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343324/why-in-the-output-of-script-1-the-newline-is-cr-lf-dos-style) and it seems this is by design. Though I'm not sure how to fix it.

These line endings cause issues when viewing the logs in `lnav`:

[image]

The reason for this becomes quickly apparent upon inspecting the raw text:

[image]

I have thought of some potential options, but not sure how to implement:

1. Fix the output of the `script(1)` utility so that single CR are converted to LF. Maybe this can be achieved with piping or some argument?
2. A hack for `lnav` to treat CR as LF when displaying in the GUI.

Does anyone know how I can fix these line breaks so it shows correctly in `lnav`?

Comment: most probably the command [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) can fix it for you.

Comment: @pynexj The problem is it isn't a static file. I don't think I can apply dos2unix with the script(1) utility with a constantly changing log file. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: save script's output to a file and then run dos2unix on the file.

Comment: add a filter where appropriate `... | tr -d '\012'` . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
... script -a $LOGSTDOUT ...
```

with

```
... script -a >(tr -d '\r' >"$LOGSTDOUT") ...
```

- See the [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) section on the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for an explanation of `>(...)`.
- Note that ALL_UPPERCASE variable names (like `LOGSTDOUT`) are best avoided because there is a danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).
- The quotes on `$LOGSTDOUT` are necessary in general.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common problems with shell code, including missing quotes.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I also appreciate the links! I ended up using a modified version of the above: `>(tr '\r' '\n' | cat -s >> "$LOGSTDOUT")`. The `tr '\r' '\n'` is for replacing CR with LF. But this creates extra blanks links, so I pipe it to `cat -s`. Finally, used `>>` instead of `>` to append to the file, not overwrite it.